# Scala eta expression ambiguous reference doesn't list all overloaded methods

Tags: scala

I'm using Scala 2.12.1. In the Interpreter I make an Int val:

```
scala> val someInt = 3
someInt: Int = 3
```

Then I tried to use the eta expansion and get the following error:

```
scala> someInt.== _
<console>:13: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method == in class Int of type (x: Char)Boolean
and  method == in class Int of type (x: Byte)Boolean
match expected type ?
       someInt.== _
               ^
```

I see in [the scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Int.html) that the Int class has more than 2 overloaded methods.

Question: is there a particular reason that the error message shows only 2 overloaded methods as opposed to listing all of them?

By the way, to specify which method you want to use the syntax is this:

```
scala> someInt.== _ : (Double => Boolean)
res9: Double => Boolean = $$Lambda$1103/1350894905@65e21ce3
```

Comment: or this: `someInt == (_: Double)`

Comment: @AndreyTyukin nice thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of the two methods that are listed seems to be more or less arbitrary. For example, this snippet:

```
class A
class B
class C

class Foo {
  def foo(thisWontBeListed: C): Unit = {}
  def foo(thisWillBeListedSecond: B): Unit = {}
  def foo(thisWillBeListedFirst: A): Unit = {}
}

val x: Foo = new Foo
x.foo _
```

fails to compile with the error message:

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method foo in class Foo of type (thisWillBeListedFirst: this.A)Unit
and  method foo in class Foo of type (thisWillBeListedSecond: this.B)Unit
match expected type ?
    x.foo _
```

That is, it simply picks the two last methods that have been added to the body of the class, and lists them in the error message. Maybe those methods are stored in a `List` in reverse order, and the two first items are picked to compose the error message.

Why does it do it? It does it, because it has been programmed to do so, I'd take it as a given fact.

What was the main reason why it was programmed to do exactly this and not something else? That would be a primarily opinion-based question, and probably nobody except the authors of the Scala compiler themselves could give a definitive answer to that. I can think of at least three good reasons why only two conflicting methods are listed:

- It's faster: why search for all conflicts, if it is already clear that a particular line of code does not compile? There is simply no reason to waste any time enumerating all possible ways how a particular line of code could be wrong.
- The full list of conflicting methods is usually not needed anyway: the error messages are already quite long, and can at times be somewhat cryptic. Why aggravate it by printing an entire wall of error messages for a single line?
- Implementation is easier: whenever you write a language interpreter of some sort, you quickly notice that returning *all* errors is somewhat more difficult than returning *just the first* error. Maybe in this particular case, it was decided not to bother collecting all possible conflicts.

PS: The order of the methods in [the source code of Int](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/Int.scala#L1) seems to be different, but I don't know exactly what this "source" code has to do with the actual `Int` implementation: it seems to be a generated file without any implementations, it's there just so that `@scaladoc` has something to process, the real implementation is elsewhere.